# MySQL server windows Installation unexplained failure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install the MySQL server 5.6.35 and it gets about 80%-90% of the way through and then rolls back, without giving any sort of error. This is the bottom chunk of the logs:

```
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 10:04:17: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 10:04:17: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 5.6 2: {99419C88-C5F8-479C-A5A4-CF59BA3A6D1D} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 5.6.35' failed.
```

I've tried this with the x86 and the x64 versions and get the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: It reminds me of the frustration I also had when installing MySQL server to the systems.   If I recall back. I uninstalled the directory of where the remaining old cache files failed on that installation and re-did the installation process again.   It may work for you, but back then it didn't work for me on one system but it did on the other system.    I had to implement a new directory name for installation and it worked.    Have you and can you tried these simple approaches?  Though my installation process took a long time as I installed enterprise level node structure.   linux = quicker

Comment: @user7568042 Actually, I think I just solved it - I downloaded the previous version installer, and *that* one picked up that I needed a new distributable VC++ package. Then that one failed, but when I tried the x86 version of that old one it worked. Yay...

Comment: Glad to hear that. Yeah usually older version works too.  Let's hope you don't have to go through that ordeal again with potential Oracle setup too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I managed to get a version installed. I downloaded the 5.5.54 installer, which picked up that I needed a new VC++ distributable. After installing that it still didn't work with the x64 version, but the x86 version did work, which is enough for me I guess...